# Fix Errors in GSC

Tags: url, parameters, google-search

Help me remove the URL parameters page/16/?post_type=tribe_events&eventDisplay=day&eventDate=2016-12-01&paged=16 from my all posts. Full URL: https://www.ottawahousemuseum.ca/?post_type=tribe_events&eventDisplay=day&eventDate=2020-03-01&paged=9 and https://www.ottawahousemuseum.ca/events/list/page/16/?tribe-bar-date=2017-02-01

It's causing errors on GSC. My site is hosted on siteground.

No errors in GSC or minimized errors